# What is the solid of revolution of an ellipsis around a general line through the origin?

Tags: geometry

If one rotates an ellipsis around its major axis, one gets a prolate ellipsoid. Around the minor axis, ones gets an oblate ellipsoid. What about a general line through the origin?

Comment: lots of weird donut/ring shapes if it doesnt pass through the ellipse. if it passes through the ellipse, lots of terrible vase/bowl designs. if its tangent to the ellipse, parallel to the major axis you can something like this http://www.hawkin.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/E15849_800.jpg

Comment: Related: [Volume of Revolution of a Transformed Ellipse?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550106).